# If I export developer account from Xcode does it export push certificates

Tags: xcode, certificate

I exported developer account with distribution certificate to another machine with xcode export option.  Does it export Apple push certificates for iOS or do I have to export or download them separately and how?

at least I don't see them in keychain on new machine.

Answer (score 0):

seemed to work  without doing anything. it's just miss leading that they re visible in old machines keychain where they are created and exported to server.